# Is there a concept of natural splliting?

Tags: linear-algebra, category-theory, homological-algebra

This question was motivated by contemplating why a gradient would not be defined on a smooth manifold without a Riemannian metric, which boils down to questioning why there is no canonical isomorphism between a vector space and its dual. But I felt I could give the natural isomorphism $\varphi: V\to V^*$ in this way: for each $v\in V$, it would be natural to define $\varphi(v)(v)=1$. Also I tried to mimic the 'orthogonal component'. We have the injection $\langle v\rangle\to V$, there is an exact sequence $0\to \langle v\rangle \to V \to V/\langle v\rangle \to 0$, and the sequence of vector spaces always splits. Hence $V = \langle v\rangle \oplus V/\langle v \rangle$, then we assign $\varphi(v)(w)=0$ for $w$ in second component of direct sum. At first glance, it looked like the natural isomorphism, but since I knew it was obviously incorrect, I tried few examples and concluded that there is no canonical embedding of $V/\langle v\rangle$ to $V$. This failure was due to non-canonical choice of the splitting map, so I'm curious about if there is a general notion of a canonical splitting exact sequence.

Comment: Naturality or unnaturality of splitting is very important to keep track of. You sometimes have it but usually don't in, say, the universal coefficient theorems of homological algebra, and that matters! You can make false conclusions if you assume it's natural

Comment: @FShrike Actually, that was what I found when I googled natural splitting, but I couldn't quite understand because I don't know such homological algebra yet. Anyway, thank you for letting me know that this is indeed an important concept.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The notion of a naturally splitting exact sequence is exactly a natural exact sequence along with another natural transformation that provides a splitting of each instance. As you've noticed the natural exact sequence
$$0 \to \langle v \rangle \to V \to V/\langle v \rangle \to 0,$$
evaluated at a "pointed vector space" $(V, v)$, does not have a natural splitting (at least for general $V$). However the natural exact sequence
$$0 \to V \xrightarrow{(\operatorname{id}, 0)} V \oplus V \xrightarrow{\operatorname{pr}_2} V \to 0,$$
evaluated at a vector space $V$, does have a natural splitting: $(0, \operatorname{id}) : V \to V \oplus V$ or equivalently $\operatorname{pr}_1 : V \oplus V \to V$.

If you have a natural exact sequence
$$0 \to A \xrightarrow{i} B \xrightarrow{p} C \to 0,$$
of vector spaces with inner products (to be precise only $B$ needs to a priori have an inner product) then it does have a natural splitting, given by $B \ni v \mapsto u \in A$ uniquely defined by $v - i(u) \perp i(A)$ (or equivalently $C \ni w \mapsto v \in B$ uniquely defined by $v \perp i(A)$ and $p(w) = v$).

Comment: Before accepting your answer, may I ask for more detail as I'm still confused about functoriality and naturality? So in your first example, $(0, id)$ is the natural splitting in the sense that it is a natural transformation from the identity functor to the functor $V\mapsto V\oplus V$? I think then "pointed vector space" you mentioned make sense, as $V\mapsto V/\langle v \rangle$ is a functor between the pointed vector space. So the naturality really means the square diagram consisting of $V, V\oplus V, W, W\oplus W$ commutes, right?

Comment: I'll just accept it since it looks correct after posting the comment. Please let me know if there is any misunderstanding in above comment.

Comment: @okaberintarou yes, I'm thinking of the functors $(V, v) \mapsto V$, $(V, v) \mapsto V/\langle v \rangle$, $\Delta: V \mapsto V \oplus V$ etc (with obvious meaning on morphisms). Then $V \mapsto (0, \text{id}_V)$ is a natural transformation from the functor $\text{id}$ to the functor $\Delta$.